# ¿Cómo forzar la eliminación una carpeta y todos sus archivos y subdirectorios en Windows?

Tags: windows, git, cmd

Necesito borrar una carpeta de mi directorio local en Windows con todos sus archivos. Esta carpeta fue generada con el comando `git init`. Ya luego borraré el repositorio en GitHub.

1. Borré todos los archivos de manera tradicional de Windows
2. Luego fui a GitBash y ejecuté el comando `git add .`
3. Luego ejecuté el comando `git commit -m "Eliminando carpeta"`
4. Luego Ejecuté el comando `Git push -u origin master`

Hasta aquí todo bien. En GitHub no hay nada, solo el nombre del repositorio vacío al igual que en el directorio de Windows (excepto por la carpeta `.git` que está dentro del repositorio local).

Aquí comienza el problema, ya que no me deja borrarla ni desde GitBash (que debería ser lo lógico) y tampoco desde Windows (porque pide autorización nivel administrador, que no sería lo lógico).

Ejecuto el comando `git rm -r nombredelacarpeta` y dice que no existe nada `.git`

He revisado con detenimiento el `pathspec` para el comando `rm` de Git y aparentemente está bien; me he posicionado en el tree del directorio de Windows justo en el padre de la carpeta y nada, también dentro de la carpeta misma y nada. Ya no sé que hacer!

Por favor, ¿alguien podría ayudarme? Muchísimas gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no te deja borrarla windows?

Answer (score 2):

#### Solución para sistema operativo Windows:

> Al interno del cmd con permisos administrativos

- Colócate en el directorio de la carpeta .git que quieres eliminar, con el comando `cd x://dirección/.git` (sustituye con el directorio verdadero) y si está en otro disco duro diferente de C:// tendrás que lanzar antes de ese comando este otro `X:` donde X es la letra el disco duro donde se encuentra tu carpeta .git.
- Una vez dentro de la carpeta .git procede a eliminar todos sus archivos con el comando `DEL /F/Q/S*.* >NUL` el cuál forzará la eliminación y la hará de forma silenciosa sin escribir nada tampoco en la consola.
- Luego que hayas eliminado los archivos retrocede a la carpeta que contiene .git con el comando `cd..` y procede a la eliminación de la carpeta .git y de todas sus subcarpetas con el comando `RMDIR /Q/S .git`

Lo sé que es una solución bastante extrema para un problema tan pequeño considerando que siempre elimino esa carpeta con el botón `delete`, pero pediste la forma más eficaz de hacerlo.